# highcharts how to have loading animation after data update?

Tags: animation, highcharts, loading

I found similar ask on SO but my problem appears to be different. I use the official demo of highstock link: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update

Here I modified some data:
    var newData = (function () {
        var data = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;
            for (i = -199; i <= 0; i += 1) {
            data.push([
            time + i * 1000,
            Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
        ]);
    }
    return data;
}());
$(function () {

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart: {
        events: {
        }
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            count: 1,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '1M'
        }, {
            count: 5,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '5M'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }],
        inputEnabled: false,
        selected: 0
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },

    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push([
                    time + i * 1000,
                    Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                ]);
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});
$('#button').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].update({name: 'newName'});
    chart.series[0].setData(newData);
});
```

});

after button is clicked, the new charts is generated but with no loading animation. I ask this question because I saw the very similar one(s) were solved, any one can help me? many thanks and in a really big hurry~

Comment: You can remove the series and add a new one - the animation will occur - see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/UTC6e/2/)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are only setting new data to the already existing chart.

If you want to create a new chart when you click the button you have to move the chart creation inside the button click function.

You can also extend the animation when adding series using [PlotOptions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.animation):

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      animation: {
        duration: 2000
      }
    }
  },
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xsmvkgse/2/

Example without button click:

http://jsfiddle.net/meh2b8rn/

Comment: thanks for sharing jsfiddle. hmn, is it possible that you could do this without having to click a button?